# Column width not working in DataTables bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datatables, width

I am using the following code to set the column width of a DataTable. During partial page load the width appears to be correct and when it loads completely, the width is off.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#memberGrid").dataTable({
            "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
            "tableTools": {
                "sSwfPath": "../../Content/swf/copy_csv_xls.swf"
            },
            "destroy": true,
            "info": true,
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "bFilter": false,
            "bAutoWidth": false,
            "aoColumns": [{ "sWidth": "20%" }, { "sWidth": "20%" }, { "sWidth": "20%" }, { "sWidth": "10%" }, { "sWidth": "20%" }, { "sWidth": "10%" }]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Table Markup

```
<table class="group-grid table table-hover table-bordered table-responsive zebra-striped" id="memberGrid">
                <thead class="tablehead">
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width: 20%">Name</th>
                        <th style="width: 20%">Room with</th>
                        <th style="width: 20%">Extensions</th>
                        <th style="width: 10%">Travel Protection</th>
                        <th style="width: 20%">Flying from</th>
                        <th style="width: 10%">Balance</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
            <tr class="tablerows">
                <td style="width: 20%"><%# Eval("Travelers") %></td>
                <td style="width: 20%"><%# Eval("RoomMates")%></td>
                <td style="width: 20%"><%# Eval("Extensions")%></td>
                <td style="width: 10%"><%# (string) Eval("HasTpp") == "Y"? "Yes" : "No"%></td>
                <td style="width: 20%"><%# Eval("Airport")%></td>
                <td style="width: 10%">$<%# Eval("Balance")%></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Comment: How does your markup looks like?

Comment: Its using autowidth and not taking the width I specified. So certain columns are narrower than I expect it to be.

Comment: Yes, that is what we can see in the question -  but how is your markup, the table structure, i.e `<table class="x y z" id="something"><thead>....` etc?

Comment: I have updated the question with the markup of the table. @davidkonrad

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the following script when defining datatable properties:

```js
"columns": [
        { "width": "25px" },
        { "width": "25px" },
        { "width": "450px" },
        { "width": "20px" },
        { "width": "20px" },
        { "width": "20px" },
        { "width": "20px" },
        { "width": "20px" }
],
```

Comment: On my case I needed to add "autoWidth: false" as well. Above only not worked for me.

Comment: This is a good answer but will only work with DataTables v1.10 and up. OP's question appears to be using v1.9.

Comment: @Kidquick: The funny part is that... SHE is the OP! ;)

Answer (score 41):

When setting columns widths, you also need to set:

```
autoWidth: false
```

...on the DataTable itself

Comment: This solution helped with my issue where table with same column class receive different width when dataTable is triggered.

Comment: Setting "autoWidth" did not help me. Just removed a piece of code from library which sets autowidth for columns and it worked fine.

Comment: This was indeed what I was looking for to resolve my issue.  I had columnDef widths set and they would not change.  Changing autoWidth from true to false solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 12):

Would be nice to see your table in action, but I get a strong feeling that this is a pure matter of width of content. Elements with `display: table-cell` will try to expand in order to show as much as its content as possible without wrapping. For example, the width of the `<th>` that has the caption "Travel Protection", which you define as 10% - you would need a rather broad table to show "Travel Protection" within 10%.

So overrule the default `word-wrap` and `word-break` settings for `<th>` like this :

```css
table.dataTable thead tr th {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

a sort of demo (as said, cannot proof this to your table IRL) -> http://jsfiddle.net/9vbz7thp/

The best thing would be to adjust the content of the `<th>`'s so they fits to the hardcoded widths.

If it is the content of the `<td>`'s that grows too large (typically a loooong not breakable word) :

```css
table.dataTable tbody tr td {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

BTW: You do not need to define hardcoded widths in both `<th>` and `<td>`'s. `<td>`'s  automatically get the width from the corresponding `<th>`.

Comment: Your table doesn't wrap when you have a non-breaking word. See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9vbz7thp/32/

Comment: @kimli, this is because you wrongly target `table.dataTable thead tr td` in the updated fiddle, obviously that should be `table.dataTable TBODY tr td` -> **http://jsfiddle.net/9vbz7thp/33/** then it works.

Answer (score 11):

The only thing that worked for me was setting an inline `min-width` on the column header:

```html
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <thead>
                <th>Ref</th>
                <th style="min-width: 100px">User</th>
                <th>Organisation</th>
            </thead>     
        </tr>
        ...
    </table>
```

Answer (score 9):

```
 oTableDetails = $('#tblUserDetails').dataTable({

   "autoWidth":false,
```

is working for me

Answer (score 2):

For Auto Adjustment , Add this explicitly

```
var MyDatatable = $("#memberGrid").dataTable();


MyDatatable.columns.adjust().draw();
```

Comment: What is "MyItemst"? I don't see that anywhere in the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the problem is due to the number of columns, if there are too many it will not seem to work. Try to determine a size for the table for example:

style="width: 9000px"

With this change my problem with column width disappeared

```
                <table id="tbl-PriceDiscrepancy" class="table table-condensed table-hover" style="width: 9000px">
                <thead class="btn-dark">
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="8" style="text-align: center; background-color: indianred; padding-top: 4px">VIM</th>
                        <th colspan="19" style="text-align: center; background-color: darkslategrey; padding-top: 4px">MIRO</th>
                        <th colspan="12" style="text-align: center; background-color: cornflowerblue; padding-top: 4px">PURCHASING DOCUMENTS</th>
                        <th colspan="5" style="text-align: center; background-color: darkslateblue; padding-top: 4px">MIGO</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Dp.Vim</th>
                        <th scope="col">Vim.Doc.Type</th>
                        <th scope="col">Completed</th>
                        <th scope="col">Curent.Agent</th>
                        <th scope="col">Multi.Agent</th>
                        <th scope="col">Current.Role</th>
                        <th scope="col">Vim.Block.Status</th>
                        <th scope="col">Vim.Block.Reason</th>

                        <th scope="col">Subsequent.Debit.Credit</th>
                        <th scope="col">Blocked.Due.Price</th>
                        <th scope="col">Payment.Block.Code</th>
                        <th scope="col">Miro.Doc.Num</th>
                        <th scope="col">Plant</th>
                        <th scope="col">Company.Code</th>
                        <th scope="col">Fiscal.Year</th>
                        <th scope="col">Document.Date</th>
                        <th scope="col">Posting.Date</th>
                        <th scope="col">Reference/NF</th>
                        <th scope="col">NF.Type</th>
                        <th scope="col">Vendor.Code</th>
                        <th scope="col">Vendor.Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Miro.Total.Amount</th>
                        <th scope="col">Miro.Item.Amount</th>
                        <th scope="col">Tax.Amout</th>
                        <th scope="col">Currency</th>
                        <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
                        <th scope="col">Base.Unit</th>

                        <th scope="col">Contract.Number</th>
                        <th scope="col">Contract.Item.Number</th>
                        <th scope="col">Contract.Value</th>
                        <th scope="col">Contract.New.Value</th>
                        <th scope="col">Condition.Pricing.Unit</th>
                        <th scope="col">Purchasing.Document.Type</th>
                        <th scope="col">Purchasing.Document.Number</th>
                        <th scope="col">Purchasing.Document.Item</th>
                        <th scope="col">MatNr</th>
                        <th scope="col">Description</th>
                        <th scope="col">PO.Gross.Price</th>
                        <th scope="col">Purchase.Unit.Price</th>

                        <th scope="col">Migo.Document</th>
                        <th scope="col">Migo.Year</th>
                        <th scope="col">Migo.Amount</th>
                        <th scope="col">Migo.Quantity</th>
                        <th scope="col">Migo.Base.Unit</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
            </table>


    $('#tbl-PriceDiscrepancy').DataTable({
    "aaSorting": [[0, "desc"]],
    "lengthChange": true,
    "filter": true,
    "ordering": true,
    "info": true,
    "paging": true,
    lengthMenu: [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 50, 100, 200],
    "iDisplayLength": _displayLenght,
    columnDefs: [{
        targets: 0,
        width: "200px"
    }, {
        targets: 1,
        width: "200px",
    }, {
        targets: 2,
        width: "500px",
        className: "centerCol"
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var reCalculateLayoutDatatable = function(){
reCalculateLayoutDatatableYN = true;
setTimeout(function(){
  var tableHeaderWidth = 0;
  $("body").find("div.dataTables_scrollHeadInner table tr.row-header th").each(function() {
    var cols = 1;
    if(parseInt($(this).attr("colspan")) > 1) {
      cols = parseInt($(this).attr("colspan"));
    }
    tableHeaderWidth += parseInt($(this).attr("data-col-width")) + (15 * cols);
  });
  $("body").find("div").css("width","auto");
  $("body").find("table").css("width","auto");
  $("body").find("div.dataTables_scrollBody table").css("width",tableHeaderWidth + "px");
  $("body").find("div.dataTables_scrollHeadInner table").css("width",tableHeaderWidth + "px");
  $("body").find("th,td").each(function(){
    if($(this).attr("data-col-width") > 0){
      $(this).css("width",$(this).attr("data-col-width") +"px");
    }
  });
},50);
}
$( window ).resize(function() {
   if (reCalculateLayoutDatatableYN == true) {
     reCalculateLayoutDatatable();
   }
});
$( document ).ready(function() {
    reCalculateLayoutDatatable();
});
```

HTML:

```
<table id="datatableLarge" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr class="row-header" >
       <th data-col-width="100">管理番号</th>
       <th data-col-width="350">物件名</th>
       <th data-col-width="40">号室</th>
       <th data-col-width="100" >
          管理区分
       </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td data-col-width="100">1234</td>
       <td data-col-width="350">物件1</td>
       <td data-col-width="40">号室1</td>
       <td data-col-width="100" >
          管理区分
       </td>
  </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually had to take the opposite approach and delete the autoWidth line (same as autoWidth:true) and remember to put the desired width in the same object as my data:

```
"columns": [{ 'data': 'account.organization_Name', width: '120px' }]
```

As seen here:  http://live.datatables.net/jatazeho/1/edit